Is VSTest's Logger::WriteMessage not thread-safe?
I am seeing unexplained test failures when using Visual Studio 2022's VSTest's Logger::WriteMessage from multiple threads. In normal runs, I see
Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 26
     Passed: 26
 Total time: 3.1651 Seconds

while occasionally, I instead see
Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

at the end of a test, and something like
Test Run Failed.
Total tests: 17
     Passed: 17
 Total time: 2.2211 Seconds

at the end of such a test run.
In the IDE, this is noticeable by "Run Until Failure" running for 1000 iterations, but reporting passes for less than 1000 iterations (but no failures!).
This is the code that reproduces the problem. It is highly optimized to reproduce the problem after <10 test runs:
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include "CppUnitTest.h"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Logger;

namespace NamespaceFoo {
TEST_CLASS (ClassFoo) {
#define TEST(NAME)                                  \
    TEST_METHOD (NAME) {                            \
        std::vector<std::jthread> threads;          \
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                \
            threads.emplace_back([] {               \
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms); \
                Logger::WriteMessage("Message");    \
            });                                     \
    }

    TEST(A)
    TEST(B)
    TEST(C)
    TEST(D)
    TEST(E)
    TEST(F)
    TEST(G)
    TEST(H)
    TEST(I)
    TEST(J)
    TEST(K)
    TEST(L)
    TEST(M)
    TEST(N)
    TEST(O)
    TEST(P)
    TEST(Q)
    TEST(R)
    TEST(S)
    TEST(T)
    TEST(U)
    TEST(V)
    TEST(W)
    TEST(X)
    TEST(Y)
    TEST(Z)
};
}  // namespace NamespaceFoo

This is in Visual Studio 2022 v17.10.4 using MSVC 14.34.31931 (from Visual Studio 2022 v17.4).
To run it:
"%VS2022INSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -arch=amd64
for /L %i in () do @(vstest.console.exe Demo_VSTest.dll)

Logger::WriteMessage seems to be hardly documented, so I wonder if my use of it from multiple threads may cause the problems I am seeing. I have noticed that locking a mutex before writing log messages helps, but I wonder if  that is necessary.

Any API should usually be assumed to be not thread safe unless it explicitly documents that it is thread safe.

Why do you expect the API to be threadsafe? In general that is a wrong assumption, the reason that making code threadsafe has costs.

@RichardCritten in general, I agree, but I kind of expected that static logging facilities in a non-performance-critical(?) test framework that supports parallel execution of tests would be thread safe. Maybe I was wrong.

Most libraries stick to C++'s idiom : Don't pay for what you don't use. And in fairness, most unit tests are not (and should not be) multithreaded. Multithreaded tests usually are already a first order integration test.

In the reference docs: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework API reference there is no mention of any sort of thread support or the word "parallel".

@RichardCritten vstest.console.exe has a --Parallel|/Parallel argument, compare https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2022#general-command-line-options. Parallel tests can also be enabled in the Test Explorer, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2022#run-tests
